# Is there any commodity WiFi device supports dynamic OFDM subcarriers selection in demodulation?

Tags: ofdm

For example, given an OFDM symbol with $N$ subcarriers, the WiFi device only demodulates subcarriers $1$ to $N_{1}$, and ignore subcarriers $N_{1} + 1$ to $N$, where $1 < N_{1}  < N$?

Is there any commodity device support this feature?

Comment: You'd have to dive into the device's firmware, and as far as I know all commercial firmware is closed-source.

Comment: Well, none of the commodity devices I can think of will allow **you** to do that. Their firmware will certainly allow the manufacturer to do just that.

Comment: You're asking a typical X/Y question. See: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).